# ADB claiming that I'm already connected to device IP address as another device's IP address

Tags: android, adb

I'm attempting to connect to multiple devices in the run up to a live event using the ADB connect command after setting them all to run the daemon on the default TCPIP port (5555). This was working absolutely fine back in our main office and ADB retained a connection to every device, allowing us to push commands to individual devices by IP address and create Python scripts to semi-automate everything. As soon as we got set up on-site, however, I've been getting a weird error when attempting to connect to some devices:

```
> adb connect 10.20.30.400:5555
Connected to 10.20.30.400:5555
> adb connect 10.20.30.401:5555
Already connected to 10.20.30.401:5555 (as 10.20.30.400:5555)
```

This only seems to occur on the PC I'm using, not others, and no amount of **adb kill/start-server** or **adb disconnect** seems to resolve it. I also weirdly get the same error when attempting to use different ports for each device, so that's not a viable solution.

I guess my question is: why does this issue occur and is there something cached on the PC that might cause this type of problem to persist (since it's only occurring on the PC we're using).

Comment: is that the only difference the PC, or is it a different network and different router as well?

Comment: It's the same local network and router. No changes there.

Comment: it's weird that you explain it worked well "in the main office, but once on site" the difference was you had "a different PC but same local network and router"